# Taking the ith row of a data frame, and subtracting it by ith component of a vector

Tags: r

I have a feeling `apply` (or some variation of `apply`) is involved here.

Consider the following:

```
x <- matrix(c(1, 2,
              3, 4), 
            ncol = 2, 
            nrow = 2, 
            byrow=TRUE)
y <- c(1, 2)
```

I would like to take the ith row of x, and subtract from it the ith component of y, for i = 1, 2.

The final output should be

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    1    2
```

I thought maybe

```
apply(X = x, MARGIN = 1, FUN = '-', y)

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    2
[2,]    0    2
```

would do the trick, but this is wrong. My guess is what's happening here is that each row of x is being treated as a two-dimensional vector, and is then subtracted from `y` (and I recall from a previous class that `apply`, for some reason, transposes this result).

I would be particularly interested in doing this without having to `cbind` the matrix and vector together, and creating a calculated field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you could just do:

```
> x - y
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    1    2
```

Comment: My math brain does not comprehend this, but thank you.

Comment: @Clarinetist This is more of an interesting property with R called recycling combined with the fact that R matrices are ordered as column vectors (not exactly right, but adequate for this problem). The vector y is first applied to element x[1,1] the second element of y to x[2,1] then y is recycled so that the first element of y is applied to x[1,2] and the second element of y is applied to x[2,2]. To get a feel for how recycling works, play around with subtracting vectors of various lengths. `1:10 - 1:5` or `1:10 - 1:3` or `1:3 - 1:5`.